# What causes curled leaves in ctetanthe pilosa?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health

I have recently purchased a small ctetanthe pilosa, about 6 inches tall. I have it inside with morning sun through glass window. Temp outside is cold winter between 3 degrees and 10 degrees at the moment. The leaves are curling up in last couple days. Not sure whats going on. Could you help me out as this was noy cheap.

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] add a photo or two, it‘s always easier to judge what’s going on if we can *see* the symptoms. I would also recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Oh, and as this is an international community: it’s always good to give a unit - are we talking about degrees *Celsius* or *Fahrenheit*?